# How to use procedure SetChannel in PasLibVlcUnit in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I tried to use component PasLibVlc and intended to try the procedure SetChannel but dont know what param value to pass, tried

```
PasLibVlcPlayer1.SetChannel(libvlc_AudioChannel_Left);
```

or

```
PasLibVlcPlayer1.SetChannel(3);
```

but raised errors.

The procedure :

```
procedure TPasLibVlcPlayer.SetChannel(chanel: libvlc_audio_output_channel_t);
begin
  if not Assigned(p_mi) then exit;
  libvlc_audio_set_channel(p_mi, chanel);
end;
```

and the params :

```
libvlc_audio_output_channel_t = (
libvlc_AudioChannel_Error   = -1,
libvlc_AudioChannel_Stereo  =  1,
libvlc_AudioChannel_RStereo =  2,
libvlc_AudioChannel_Left    =  3,
libvlc_AudioChannel_Right   =  4,
libvlc_AudioChannel_Dolbys  =  5
 );
```

Please anyone elaborate me using procedure like this, since my knowledge still the basic one :-(. Thank you.

Hidayat B.

Comment: "It raised errors". What errors? Be precise.

Comment: "raised errors" is not a problem description, unless you include the details of *what errors* it raised. You have the information right in front of you - there is absolutely not reason to fail to include it in your question. Why make us guess when you know and can tell us?

Comment: Sorry, for incomplete info. I got error : 'Undeclared identifier' when using SetChannel(libvlc_AudioChannel_Left).

Comment: The problem is I dont know what param value to pass, so I tried 'libvlc_AudioChannel_Left' or if I use '3' as the param value raised 'Incompatible types: 'libvlc_audio_output_channel_t' and 'Integer''

Comment: Undeclared identifier is what it says. Where did you define the identifier.

Comment: @ David : The PasLibVlc is an open source component develeped by Robert Jêdrzejczyk  [link](http://ovoplayer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/import-engines/PasLibVlcUnit.pas), and I use it in an my app. As I said earlier, I don't know how to pass a param value if the procedure just like I quoted in my original question.

Comment: You know the type of the parameters to the functions. So pass them.

Comment: That's the problem : I don't know what the param value is. Please bear in mind that my knowledge of Delphi still in basic state, not as you Gurus'.

Comment: As an additional info, I downloaded the component from http://prog.olsztyn.pl/paslibvlc/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see your problem. You need to add PasLibVlcUnit to your uses clause in your unit like this:

```
Uses
  PasLibVlcUnit;
```

Then it would be able to find the declaration of libvlc_AudioChannel_Left.

Comment: Thank you, that's the culprit. You saved my days :-).